# New @for loop in angular 17

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular17

I want to display items of an array of strings from index 1.

```
arr = [ "str1", "str2", "str3", "str4", "str5" ]
```

Output should be:

```
str2
str3
str4
str5
```

Print all except first one, using new **@for** loop in angular.

Comment: Please do some basic [research](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch) before asking. Angular has [documentation about `@for` on their site](https://angular.io/api/core/for)

Comment: Please go through [Angular documentation](https://angular.dev/api/core/@for#mat-tab-content-88-0) basic usage of **@for** which has several implicit variables for eg: **$first** for first row/ element of loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another:

```
@for(a of arr;let first=$first;track $index) {
     @if(!first)
     {
       {{a}}
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The slice Pipe is what you are looking for :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [SlicePipe],
  template: `
    @for(a of arr|slice:1; track $index) {
      {{a}}
    }
  `,
})
export class App {
  arr = [1,2,3,4];
}
```